# how to adjust ibook screen to be more brighter in SINGLE USER mode

Tags: macos, mac

how to adjust ibook g4 screen to be more brighter when started in console SINGLE USER mode

It seems that external screen is not enabled  for some reason in single user mode, and my internal screen is so dark that its almost invisible (I can view the text only with flashlight from a few upper rows)

Answer (score 2):

Your backlight does not seem to be functioning. You could try :

***1.Zapping the PRAM:***

Restart the Mac and before the grey screen appears, hold down

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Hold the keys down until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for the second time.

Release the keys.

***2.Reset Open Firmware Settings:***

Restart Mac and during startup, hold down
<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Then in Open Firmware, enter the following:

```
0 > reset-nvram
Press Return
0 > reset-all
Press Return
```

I have seen both of these techniques bring a seemingly dead backlight back to life.

Comment: step 1 just fixed my old iBook G4 running a newly installed Jessie. Cool!